# How to create or update hMail Server configuration like Domains, SSL certificate, Protocols using powershell

Tags: microsoft-graph-mail, hmail-server

I am not able to use PowerShell commands to create or update Domains, SSL certificate, Protocols.

Can any one please share suggestions on hMail server configuration using PowerShell commands.

Tried to add hMail Server domain under Domains using PowerShell script, but unable to add domain.

below script used but not worked.

```
# Create an instance of the hMailServer COM object
$hMailServer = New-Object -ComObject hMailServer.Application`your text`

# Authenticate using an administrative account
$hMailServer.Authenticate('Administrator', 'YourPassword')

# Create a new domain
$newDomain = $hMailServer.Domains.Add()
$newDomain.Name = 'example.com'
$newDomain.Active = $true
$newDomain.Save()

# Release resources
$hMailServer.Disconnect()
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($hMailServer) | Out-Null
```